How to resctict spesific routes when user is authenticated in Clerk?
import { clerkMiddleware, createRouteMatcher } from '@clerk/nextjs/server'

const isProfileRoute = createRouteMatcher(\['/profile(.*)'\])
const isRegisterRoute = createRouteMatcher(\['/register(.*)', '/login(.\*)'\])

export default clerkMiddleware((auth, req, res) =\> {
if (isProfileRoute(req)) {
auth().protect({ unauthenticatedUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/login' })
}
if (auth().userId && isRegisterRoute(req)) {
//... what code there?
}
}, {debug: true})

export const config = {
matcher: \['/((?!.*\\..*|\_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'\],
}

If user is signed in and he goes to /regiter and /login routes how can I restrict that by redirecting him to main page /?
